# Using a while/for loop with the 'find' command to copy files and directories

Tags: linux, find, cp

I have the follwoing problem: I want to make a script that backups a certain directory completely to another directory. I may not use cp -r or any other recursive command. So I was thinking of using a while or for loop. The directory that needs to be back upped is given with a parameter. This is what I have so far:

```
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'

for file in `find $1`
do
  cp $file $HOME/TestDirectory
done

IFS="$OIFS"
```

But when I execute it, this is what my terminal says: Script started, file is typescript

Comment: I'd use `find` with `-exec` parameter or `find -print0` with the `xargs -0` command instead of for or loops.

Comment: That was my first idea as well, but I'm not allowed to use that.

Comment: Weird requirement, sounds like a homework.

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use `-exec` or `-print0` and `xargs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
find "$1" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t $HOME/TestDirectory
```

Don't run your script through `script` !

Add this (shebang) at top of file:

```
#!/bin/bash

find "$1" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t $HOME/TestDirectory
```

change permission of your script for adding `executable` flag:

```
chmod +x myScript
```

run your script localy whith arguments:

```
./myScript rootDirectoryWhereSearchForFiles
```

Comment: Thanks! And I now know why my terminal said "file is script". That was because I named the script "script".